# Array of json inside string to Array of json nodejs

Tags: node.js

I am having string in two format as

`[{"a":"a1"},{"a":"a2"}]'`

I actually extract it in array:

```
[{"a":"a1"},{"a":"a2"}]
```

How to convert it?

Comment: use `JSON.parse()`

Comment: its not a proper JSON, you dont have comma (`,`).

Comment: that was a typo i guess

Comment: @MuhammadFaizan thanks,corrected

Comment: @AkashDathan,it should be helpful for others who see it.so typo should also be corrected.

Comment: yeah yeah, i agree

Comment: JSON.parse wont work here, its not a json

Comment: `'[{"a":"a1"},{"a":"a2"}]'` is the correct string and the correct json. `"[{"a":"a1"},{"a":"a2"}]"` is not even a proper string

Comment: ok,i got your point @AkashDathan,can something be done of second fomat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Use `JSON.parse()`

```js
    const string = '[{"a":"a1"},{"a":"a2"}]'
    
    const res = JSON.parse(string)
    
    console.log('Result : ', res)
```

Answer (score 0):

here is your string as `arrayString`:

```
const arrayString = `[{"a":"a1"},{"a":"a2"}]`;

JSON.parse(arrayString); // here you will find your desired result.
```

you can use `JSON.parse` to parse data JSON that is in string format